# Regular Expression for Dominion Land Surveyor

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm have been playing with regular expressions for Dominion Land Surveyor (DLS) locations. I want to this format to be enforced on the keyup event of an html input textbox, so I am attempting to do this through jQuery and javascript.
The format is: xx-xx-xxx-xxWx
where
-the first two x's can be between 01 and 16
-the dash is a dash
-the next two x's can be between 01 and 36
-the next three x's can be between 001 and 127
-the next two x's can be between 01 and 34
-the W is a Wt
-the last x can be between 1-8
Using regexpal.com, I was able to confirm that the expression:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[0-6])[/-](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-6])[/-](0[0-9][1-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|1[2][0-7])[/-](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-4])[W][1-8]$
```

This works how I want it to work, but I cannot get past the syntax errors when attempting to integrate this into my jQuery replace method. I have only modified the regular expression to include a starting and ending forward slash.
Here is the method I am attempting to execute on the keyup event:

```
function LsdLocation(obj) {
   var value = obj.val();
   var regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-6])[/-](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-6])[/-](0[0-9][1-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|1[2][0-7])[/-](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-4])[W][1-8]$/;
   value = value.replace(regex, '');
   obj.val(value);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've got `/` chars in your expression. Even if you were to escape them, do you actually need them there?

Comment: Probably, escape the backslashes in the classes.

Comment: I'm imagining that the keyup event is looking for boundry conditions, not really a validation regex.

Comment: I wasn't able to escape the '-' character with [-], so I escaped it with the [/-] and had it working. If I put the regular expression from the top into my javascript var regex, the first ^ has an expected expression which throws a javascript error. How does the var regex need to be formatted to allow the expression.

My apologies, this is my first time using regular expressions in javascript.

Comment: `a javascript error` isn't very much you're giving us.
How about you copy the `exact` error message here?

Comment: Try `'/^(0[1-9]|1[0-6])[\/-](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-6])[\/-](0[0-9][1-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|1[2][0-7])[\/-](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-4])[W][1-8]$/';`
`

Comment: no, regex should be assigned a regexp, not a string.
If you want a string, then replace the // with '' but you have to escape metacharacters now. Better to stay with the regex.

Comment: So you meant to use \ instead of / to escape it? If you just want a literal hyphen, you don't need a character class `[]` at all.

Comment: The regex engine probably sees this `/^(0[1-9]|1[0-6])[/`

Comment: how about `/^(0[1-9]|1[0-6])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-6])-(0[0-9][1-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|1[2][0-7])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-4])[W][1-8]$/` then?

Comment: Why does the SO parser put little square chars sometimes in the quoted comments?

Comment: Show us the code where and how you use `LsdLocation`.
Show us the syntax errors you can't get past.

Comment: @sln are you copying characters with incorrect encoding?
Provide a link to such a comment!

Comment: @stackunderflow I tried your regex and I didn't get an error but I can enter anything I want in the textbox.  Am I going about this the wrong way?  I have been using this sort of regex on the keyup event for enforcing that only ints or floats are entered into a textbox and have had great success.  Does this strategy not apply to attempting to force the input to adhere to a specific format? My goal was to be able to do this validation on the client-side not server-side if possible.
Huge thanks for the prompt help guys, thus proving why stackoverflow rules.

Comment: @BeeDub5 you are not answering my questions. Please do that first.

Comment: @stackunderflow sorry, here is the html markup where the function is called:
<input id="txt1" type="text" onkeyup="LsdLocation($(this))" value="01-01-001-01W1" />
If you need any other information please let me know.

Comment: @BeeDub5 - Where is the `LsdLocation`?

Comment: @sln the function LsdLocation is in a javascript file that is referenced by the web forms aspx page. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a self-contained answer (non-jquery).

See comments in the code.

It does not clear the input value.

Instead it provides background color feedback as user gets closer to entering valid data.

The code below is also available as [DominionLandSurveyor.js](http://jsfiddle.net/anaran/bd8HK/)

Thanks @sln for the incremental regexp idea.

```
// My answer for
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507396/regular-expression-for-dominion-land-surveyor/20508597?noredirect=1#comment30663755_20508597
// Use it in Firefox Scratchpad or Google Chrome devtools Snippets.
 /* jslint browser: true */
 /*global console: false*/
     'use strict';
(function testDominionLandSurveyor() {
    var inp = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
    inp.type = 'text';
    inp.value = '01-01-001-01W1';
    inp.title = 'e.g. 16-36-127-34W8';
    inp.onkeyup = function LsdLocation(obj) {
        var value = obj.target.value;
        // Based on idea by sln in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20508410/743358
        // Match incrementally, producing ever more subexpression matches until fully matched.
        var regex = /^(?:(0(?:[1-9])?|1(?:[0-6])?)(?:-(?:(0(?:[1-9])?|1(?:[0-9])?|2(?:[0-9])?|3(?:[0-6])?)(?:-(?:(0(?:[0-9](?:[1-9])?)?|1(?:[0-1](?:[0-9])?)?|1(?:[2](?:[0-7])?)?)(?:-(?:(0(?:[1-9])?|1(?:[0-9])?|2(?:[0-9])?|3(?:[0-4])?)(?:W(?:([1-8]))?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)$/;
        var matches = regex.exec(value);
        console.log(matches);
        if (matches) {
            var unmatched = matches.filter(function(value) {
                return value === undefined;
            });
            console.log(unmatched);
            obj.target.style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(360,100%,'
            // Increase luminance with each component match, up to white.
            + (100 - 8 * unmatched.length) + '%)';
            console.log(obj.target.style.backgroundColor);
        } else {
            obj.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
    // obj.target.value = value;
    };
})();
```

Comment: I'll try this out tomorrow. Thanks stackunderflow!

Comment: I gave this a try and you can enter anything you want. It doesn't enforce the regular expression. 

This is the html input textbox and the LsdLocation function I call uses 'event' instead of yours that has 'obj'

<input id="txt1" type="text" onkeyup="LsdLocation(event)" value="01-01-001-01W8" />

What does your html input textbox look like?

Comment: Impressive, this does the validation perfectly and even more than I could have anticipated with the styling. Thank you very much!

Comment: Matches `1-` when it shouldn't.

Comment: Hi @sin see http://jsfiddle.net/anaran/bd8HK/ which corresponds to my unchanged answer from above, which I originally conceived as a Google Chrome (or Firefox) snippet. You will note that `1-` is almost completely right (but not quite like an empty field). BTW, the regexp you wrote is Perl, right? How would you use that in our context?

Comment: Your regex allows optional secondary numbers, which is fundamentally different than mine which optionally, requires them as either an edge condition or within the body. Broken down, the differenc is mine: `^(0(?:[1-9]|$)|1(?:[0-6]|$))-?$`, yours: `^(0[1-9]?|1[0-6]?)-?$` Both match `15-`, but only yours matches `1-`. As for the  Perl question, the answer is no. The regex complies with any engine that supports extended mode. For example `(?:xxx)` is one construct. I use program `RegexFormat 4` http://regexformat.com to process/work on the OP's sample, does it all.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but a key-up event will look that a partial match is valid.
When accepted, the entire form must exist as a complete validation regex.

Its picky, but an edge condition (partial match) follows a simple concept of a
progressively (rolling) optional matching sequence, always terminated by EOS,
end of string. Each optional segment must have its first layer (chars) as
non-optional.

Would seem to be a recursive algo that could probably be done while parsing the regex
(if you develop those things).

Here is an example:
Edit - This regex may look big, but it has per-second excution speed much faster than the keyboard electronics software buffer.

```
 #  /^(0(?:[1-9]|$)|1(?:[0-6]|$))(?:-(?:(0(?:[1-9]|$)|[12](?:[0-9]|$)|3(?:[0-6]|$))(?:-(?:(0(?:[0-9](?:[1-9]|$))?|1(?:[0-1](?:[0-9]|$))?|1(?:[2](?:[0-7]|$))?)(?:-(?:(0(?:[1-9]|$)|[12](?:[0-9]|$)|3(?:[0-4]|$))(?:W(?:[1-8]|$))?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/

 ^           # BOS - Key pressed, if its a printable character, has to be 0 or 1 here 
 (
      0
      (?: [1-9] | $ )   # EOS
   |  1
      (?: [0-6] | $ )   # EOS
 )
 (?:        # The rest are optional
      -
      (?:
           (
                0
                (?: [1-9] | $ )   # EOS
             |  [12] 
                (?: [0-9] | $ )   # EOS
             |  3
                (?: [0-6] | $ )   # EOS
           )
           (?:
                -
                (?:
                     (
                          0
                          (?:
                               [0-9] 
                               (?: [1-9] | $ )   # EOS
                          )?
                       |  1
                          (?:
                               [0-1] 
                               (?: [0-9] | $ )   # EOS
                          )?
                       |  1
                          (?:
                               [2] 
                               (?: [0-7] | $ )   # EOS
                          )?
                     )
                     (?:
                          -
                          (?:
                               (
                                    0
                                    (?: [1-9] | $ )   # EOS
                                 |  [12] 
                                    (?: [0-9] | $ )   # EOS
                                 |  3
                                    (?: [0-4] | $ )   # EOS
                               )
                               (?:
                                    W
                                    (?: [1-8] | $ )   # EOS
                               )?
                          )?
                     )?
                )?
           )?
      )?
 )?
 $   # EOS
```

Comment: What is this? Perl extended regexp?
How are you using this in jquery or JavaScript?
Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this regular expression. Might be useful for your project.
Let me know if you have any confusion. Please follow the link

```
var regex = /^((?:([S][E])|(?:[S][W])|(?:[N][W])|(?:[N][E]))(?:(0(?:[1-9])?|1(?:[0-9])?))(?:-(?:(0(?:[1-9])?|1(?:[0-9])?|2(?:[0-9])?|3(?:[0-6])?)))(?:-(?:(0(?:[1-9])?|1(?:[0-9])?|2(?:[0-9])?|3(?:[0-6])?)))(?:-(?:W(?:(0([1-8]))|[1-8])?|((0([1-8]))|[1-8])?)?)?)$/;
```